# Number of ways to multiply elements with a non-associative operation

Tags: combinatorics

The question comes from considerations in algebra but it's probably more related to combinatorics.

Suppose I have a set of $n$ elements $(a, b, c, ...)$ and a possibly non-associative operation $*$ between these elements.

What I want to do is to count the number of elements I could obtain with this operation without interchanging the order of the elements.

Let me illustrate this. Here below the parentheses mean that the operation has higher priority (usual notation).

- For $a$ and $b$, there is only 1 way to multiply them: $a * b$.
- For $a$, $b$ and $c$, we can have 2: $a*(b*c)$ or $(a*b)*c$.
- For $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$, there are 5: $(a*b)*(c*d)$, $((a*b)*c)*d$, $(a*(b*c))*d$, $a*((b*c)*d)$ or $a*(b*(c*d))$.

It seems that for $5$ elements we have $14$ possibilities unless I've made a mistake by enumerating them all by hand.

Would anyone have an idea on how many could we obtain for $n$ elements? I fail to detect a pattern here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The number of ways of inserting parentheses into $n$ objects is given by the $n-1$'th [Catalan number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) (the relationship is mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics)):
$$C_{n-1}=\frac{1}{n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}.$$
For example, $C_4=\frac{1}{5}\binom{8}{4}=14$.

Comment: It's the $n-1$th Catalan number. $C_4=14$, $C_5=\frac{1}{6}\binom{10}{5}=42$.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for the correction, I answered too hastily :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I surely haven't heard of these before.

Comment: @Liudas: Neil Sloane's legendary [on-line encyclopedia of integer sequences](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C5%2C14&language=english&go=Search) gives you more information than you probably care to know:-) This property is second on the list.